# Conflict in .htaccess URL writing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two different php pages page.php and team.php. The Rule I've writtent for rewriting page.php is as follow

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ /page.php?name=$1&id=$2
```

It will redirect the link `example.com/privacy_policy/30` to `example.com/page.php?name=privacy_policy&id=30`

Now I want to write the Rule for team.php so that the link `example.com/team/Zeeshan_Lalani/3` will redirect to `example.com/team.php?name=Zeeshan_Lalani&id=3`

The Rule I've tried to accomplish above url

```
RewriteRule ^team/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ /team.php?name=$1&id=$2
```

But with this rule it have conflicts with page.php rule and renders `404 not found` error and when I comment the page.php rule it works fine.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and use the [L] flag. The flag says that if the statement is correct, no other statements will be matched. Ex:

```
RewriteRule ^team/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ /team.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$ /page.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Be sure to have the "Team" rule above the other one, otherwise the second rule might match before the team rule can be applied.